# Canon 7D Mark 2?

Tags: canon, canon-7d

Do you think there will be a Canon 7D replacement/successor in the foreseeable future (next 3-5 years)?

I'm considering buying one, but if there's a new one coming out in, say 18 months, I'd rather wait to either see the current one's price drop or to get a still better camera at the same price.

Comment: Please see this: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras Welcome to Stack Exchange, but we try not to speculate on unknowables, and only Canon knows there strategy here. It's inevitable that there will be some new camera and current models made obsolete, but we can't guess when it exactly what. With a 3-5 year timeframe, the answer is "definitely something by then", but also: "if you don't have a nice camera now, life is too short to sit around waiting for a hypothetical future release."

Comment: Don't worry, it will be about 30 months until the 7DII will be introduced in the Fall of 2014. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

*No one can tell you Canon's plan, not even Canon until they are confirmed.*

Looking at the 7D specifically, it was launched 2 1/2 years ago. If you look at the historical [time between upgraded models](http://www.neocamera.com/list_cameras.php?brand=canon&type=slr) there is usually about 2 years between them, with the 5D Mark III appearing 3 1/2 after the Mark II which is one of the longest periods.

Based on this, *I would* expect a follow up to the 7D within 12 months. While there is a possibility of a line being discontinued, it would be extremely unlikely for the 7D. It is Canon's only APS-C DSLR with a 100% coverage viewfinder or a weather-sealed body which all competitors have. The next level up, the full-frame 5D-class, is considerably more expensive and while it remains so, the need for a 7D-class camera is not going away.